# Can I change the action of an ng-submit at run time?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
<form>
   <button type="submit">
    Do Something 1
   </button>
   <button>
    Do Something 2
   </button>
</form>
```

I would like that when the user clicks on the button "Do Something 1" that the ng-submit expression gets fired.

However is there a way I can change what's inside the submit expression so:

- if (ts.test.current && !ts.test.userTestId) the action is getTestA()
- if (ts.test.current && ts.test.userTestId) the action is getTestB()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the logic in getTest method.

```
function getTest() {
    if (ts.test.current )
        if (!ts.test.userTestId) {
            getTestA()
        } else {
            getTestB()
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

`<form ng-submit="ts.test.userTestId ? getTestA() : getTestB()">`

Comment: I was thinking of that but it's more of a last resort. What I really want is to keep all the logic on the form itself as that would make a bit more sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @vinay-k 's solution works fine. In general: Logic should go in the controller, keep the view as slim as possible.

Comment: I am starting to read some things and it says ng-submit does not work when the enter key is pressed. I did check out your example and it seems like that is the case for me.  My form has no input buttons so I am wondering if that is why it does not respond to enter. Would like to get some suggestions.

Comment: I tried this with  ng-submit="alert('hi')"  I still cannot seem to get it to work when I click the Enter key.

Comment: Expression that we specify for `ng-submit` will be evaluated in the context of scope. As alert is not a function defined on $scope, it will not be triggered. 
Have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/hApdOv2CYvu8HTN0tIMi?p=preview

Comment: Okay I see.  Can you confirm that for this to work must I have focus in the input or is the way I could just make it so I must have focus in a div on the form ?

Comment: Any of the input elements inside the form should be focussed.